# How do I format this string '8:00-9:00 AM' to a valid ISO time format?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I need to format this string so I cand send it to an angular app using fullcalendar for its calendar, so i can concatenate the start hour of the appointment to the date.

Thank you very much!, this is my first question here...

I've tried to split the string, parse it to number, and then add conditional operators.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the [how to ask a good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Perhaps try including code you've tried, any errors and their respective error stacks, as well as any other details that could help solve your issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which [ISO format?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This converts a time interval e.g. '8-9 AM', to an ISO [time interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) as recommended by Liam

```js
let timeString = '8-9 AM'

function to24Hour(timeStr) {
  let spaceIndex = timeStr.indexOf(' ');
  let beforePM = timeStr.split(' ')[1] === 'AM' ? true : false //get if before PM
  timeStr = timeStr.split(' ')[0]; //split at space and select interval string

  if (!timeStr.includes('-')) return 'invalid interval'; //if no interval
  let startTime, endTime, interval, startEndArr = timeStr.split('-');
  startTime = startEndArr[0];
  endTime = startEndArr[1];

  if (!beforePM) {
    startTime = Number(startTime) + 12;
    endTime = Number(endTime) + 12; //PM accomodation
  };

  if (startTime.length === 1) startTime = `0${startTime}`; //append 0 to front
  if (endTime.length === 1) endTime = `0${endTime}`;

  interval = endTime - startTime; //get interval

  if (beforePM) {
    return `P${interval}H/${startTime}:00Z` //return AM formatted ISO interval
  } else {
    return `P${interval}H/${startTime}:00Z` //return PM formatted ISO interval
  };
}

console.log(to24Hour(timeString));
```

Comment: `08-00-00` is **not** a [valid ISO time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#times)

Comment: the correct format to use to represent what the OP is asking for would probably be a [Interval format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) which would look something like `P1H/09:00Z`

Comment: @Liam Corrected to output ISO format. Thanks for pointing this out, learning about it was interesting.